# Why does onClick on input type=submit in a Form automatically change back the state I set?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, onclick, use-state

I am trying to make a simple "verify your payment by uploading a bank transfer picture".
I created a "isSent" state, and a function where it would turn "isSent" from false, to true.

if true, I want the text to appear "you have submitted your verification".
So far it "works". The problem is, when I clicked on the input:submit, it only shows "you have submitted your verification" in about 1 seconds, and then it turned "isSent" to false again.

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Thank you, here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function PaymentVerification() {
  const [isSent, setisSent] = useState(false);

  const verificationSent = () => {
    setisSent(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Payment Verification</p>
      <form action=''>
        <label htmlFor=''>Please uploal your image</label>
        <input
          type='file'
          name='imageVerification'
          id='imageVerification'
          accept='image/*'
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Send for verification'
          onClick={() => verificationSent()}
        />
      </form>
      {isSent ? (
        <p>you have submitted your verification</p>
      ) : (
        <p>you havent uploaded yet</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PaymentVerification;
```

Comment: Remove onclick function (onClick={() => verificationSent()}) from your submit button and add onSubmit={handleSubmit} to your form element. So that you can have a [controlled form component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with your code, but the default behavior that the browser applies when a "submit" button is clicked.

**By default, the whole page reloads when you click on this button.** This is the reason why it behaves as you describe: the message you expect appears for a while, but then the whole page is reloaded. Because of that, all of the components are returned to their initial state.

You can fix this by using the `preventDefault` method of the `event` param passed to the event handler to prevent the browser from executing its default behavior and avoid the page reload.

```
onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  verificationSent();
}}
```